# How to get current URL before redirecting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Basically, what I wish to achieve is to trigger an event when the user navigates the page. I've seen many solutions out there that seem kind of hacky, so here's one of the solutions I have adopted (I'm open to better solutions as long as it works for the majority of apps, not just SPAs):

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
    this.save() // <- This function is meant to save the state of the current page 
});
```

The `this.save()`  Method :

```
save = () => {
    const currentUrl = window.location.href
    this.flowState.push({ // <- Storing it in an array before saving the entire thing to sessionStorage
        url: currentUrl,
    });
    sessionStorage.setItem('FLOWSTATE', JSON.stringify(this.flowState))
}
```

The problem is, this solution saves the target URL instead of the source URL, which introduces bugs to my program. Is there a good way to solve this in 2020?

Comment: You need to save the value of window.location.href before a navigation happens away from the current page so that you don't lose it. Why not put <script>var currentUrl = window.location.href</script> in the <head>?

Answer (score -2):

```
var url = window.location;
console.log(url);
```

It will show you exactly what you are looking for.